Raydium Pull Current Price per token
I'm trying to pull the current price of a solana token / shitcoin through raydium (yes I don't want the on chain price etc. I want the price from raydium)
I've tried all sorts of their APIs and either:

I have to request the API to give me the data of all pairs available and then search for the one I want (often doesn't even find it in there
It gives me completely wrong values. Like 1 token worth 200 Solana, even tho its something like 0.0000005

Would love to get pointed in the right direction, thank you!
(best would be without any 3rd party paid APIs)

Did you end up finding an answer to this? I'm also looking to do the same thing for an MVP.
